# c++ adaptor via emcc for tensorflow.js

Tags: c++, tensorflow.js, emscripten

I have a moderately large library of C++ code that uses the tensorflow_cc API. I have just started working with Emscripten/emcc and am excited by the potential to port my application to run in node.js using tensorflow.js.

I want to refactor my C++ code so that most of it can be agnostic as to which Tensorflow backend is in use. I expect that this will be done by abstracting Tensor and Model.

Is there already support for this that I have just not yet seen?

Comment: I think that this question will be of interest to the tensorflow.js team. You can maybe reach out to them on their google group

Comment: I did reach out on their discussion list and got no reply. But they specifically say: "If you have technical questions or issues, and wish to get help from the community, please use Stack Overflow and the tensorflow.js tag (not this mailing list)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear that anyone has published an interface like the one I was hoping for, but it is clearly possible to use the emscripten/embind APIs to invoke TensorFlow.js functions from C++.

My first working implementation to do this is available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jimlloyd/d26413ee9aac403a85f6329e2314d003).